# Angularjs ng-repeat-start doesn't clean old view when mode change

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<div data-ng-cloak="" data-ng-controller="Controller">
    <a data-ng-click="changeItems1()">Change Items1</a>

    <div data-ng-repeat-start="item1 in model1.items1" style="width:0;height:0;">
    </div>
    <div data-ng-repeat="item2 in model1.items2" style="border:1px #f00 solid;">
        {{ item1 }}, {{ item2 }}
    </div>
    <div data-ng-repeat-end style="display:none;">
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function Controller($scope){
        $scope.model1 = {};
        $scope.model1.items1 = [{id:"1"}, {id:"2"}, {id:"3"}, {id:"4"}];
        $scope.model1.items2 = [{id:"1a"}, {id:"2a"}, {id:"3a"}];

        $scope.changeItems1 = function(){
            $scope.model1.items1 = [{id:"1"}, {id:"2"}, {id:"3"}];
        }
    }
</script>
```

When click "Change Items1", the old rendered boxes doesn't get clean up. Any one have idea what's happening there?

Comment: Sorry, that thread doesn't answer my question. I need the inner repeat items be individual DOM items, instead of nested by outer repeat. So ng-repeat-start is required.

Comment: This seems to be a bug with Anular 1.1.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this is a Angularjs Bug. From the Angularjs bug board, there are several similar ng-repeat(-start) related defects they are working on. The following link is giving a detailed vision on how this happens:
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/3104